# How to fix: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've updated my router to take in a second main route.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// Containers & Pages
// Home
import HomePage from '/imports/ui/pages/home/HomePage.js';

// Accounts
import SignUp from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/SignUp.js';
import Login from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/Login.js';
import ForgotPassword from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/ForgotPassword.js';
import ResetPassword from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/ResetPassword.js';
import PaymentPage from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/PaymentPage.js';
import CouponPaymentPage from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/CouponPaymentPage.js';
import AccountPage from '/imports/ui/pages/accounts/AccountPage.js';

// General
import AppContainer from '/imports/ui/containers/AppContainer.js';

// In App
import DashboardContainer from '/imports/ui/containers/app/DashboardContainer.js';
import AllRecipesContainer from '/imports/ui/containers/app/AllRecipesContainer.js';

// Legal
import PrivacyPage from '/imports/ui/pages/legal/PrivacyPage.js';
import TermsPage from '/imports/ui/pages/legal/TermsPage.js';
import DisclaimersPage from '/imports/ui/pages/legal/DisclaimersPage.js';

// Admin
import AdminContainer from '/imports/ui/containers/AdminContainer.js';
import UsersAdminContainer from '/imports/ui/containers/UsersAdminContainer.js';
import RecipeStatsPage from '/imports/ui/pages/admin/RecipeStatsPage.js';

// Routes
export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
      <IndexRoute name="Home" component={HomePage} />
      <Route name="Sign Up" path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Route name="Log In" path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route name="Forgot Password" path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
      <Route name="Reset Password" path="/reset-password/:token" component={ResetPassword} />
      <Route name="Coupon Payment Page" path="/coupons/:code" component={CouponPaymentPage} />
      <Route name="Privacy Page" path="/privacy" component={PrivacyPage} />
      <Route name="Terms" path="/terms" component={TermsPage} />
      <Route name="Disclaimers" path="/disclaimers" component={DisclaimersPage} />
      <Route name="Payment" path="/payment" component={PaymentPage} />
      <Route name="Dashboard" path="/dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} />
      <Route name="Browse All Recipes" path="/browseall" component={AllRecipesContainer} />
      <Route name="Manage Account" path="/account" component={AccountPage} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/manager" component={AdminContainer}>
      <IndexRoute name="manager home" component={UsersAdminContainer} />
      <Route path="/manager/recipes" component={RecipeStatsPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

When I navigate to '/manager' in my app I get an error:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if
>   you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe
>   you meant to call this function rather than return it.
>       in Unknown (created by RouterContext)
>       in RouterContext (created by Router)
>       in Router

// AdminContainer.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import Admin from '/imports/ui/layouts/Admin.js';

export default withTracker(() => {
  const userHandle = Meteor.subscribe('users.myData');
  const loading = !userHandle.ready();
  return {
    user: Meteor.user(),
    loading,
  };
}, Admin);
```

// UsersAdminContainer.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import UsersAdminPage from '/imports/ui/pages/admin/UsersAdminPage.js';

export default withTracker(() => {
  const usersHandle = Meteor.subscribe('users.allUsers');
  const loading = !usersHandle.ready();
  return {
    loading,
    users: Meteor.users.find().fetch(),
  };
}, UsersAdminPage);
```

I've tried importing the UsersAdminPage and using that for the component of the indexroute. I've looked at this answer on SO ([Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458334/functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-this-may-happen-if-you-return-a-compon)). I'm not seeing my error any help would be much appreciated.

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "-",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor --settings dev-settings.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "contentful": "^5.1.3",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "radium": "^0.19.6",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.1.11",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-feather": "^1.0.7",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.6.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^1.2.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.4.0",
    "reactable": "github:vladnicula/reactable",
    "sib-api-v3-sdk": "^3.1.6",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.3.2",
    "stripe": "^5.5.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.1.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@meteorjs/eslint-config-meteor": "^1.0.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-meteor": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-meteor": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.2.1"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "postcss-easy-import": {
        "extensions": [
          ".css",
          ".scss",
          ".import.css"
        ]
      },
      "autoprefixer": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 2 versions"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": true,
      "allowAfterThis": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      "meteor"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "airbnb",
      "plugin:meteor/recommended"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": "meteor"
    },
    "rules": {
      "import/extensions": [
        "off",
        "never"
      ],
      "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
      "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
      "import/no-absolute-path": "off",
      "react/prefer-stateless-function": "off",
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
      "react/forbid-prop-types": "off",
      "react/require-default-props": "off",
      "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
      "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": "off",
      "class-methods-use-this": "off"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calls to `withTracker` are incorrect. They should pass the component to the result of `withTracker`:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  const userHandle = Meteor.subscribe('users.myData');
  const loading = !userHandle.ready();
  return {
    user: Meteor.user(),
    loading,
  };
})(Admin);
```

Relevant docs [here](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html).