# 'Functions are not valid as a React child' when trying to dynamically include Components for SSR bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

From my express route I'm trying to pass a component to use in a render function, that handles SSR.

**Express Route:**

```
import SettingsConnected from '../../../client/components/settings/settings-connected';

function accountTab(req, res, next) {
  sendToRenderApp(req, res, { profileInfo }, url, SettingsConnected);
}
```

**Render helper:**

```
export const sendToRenderApp = (req, res, storeObj = {}, urlPath, componentFunc) => {
  const store = configureStore(storeObj);
  const dynamicComponent = componentFunc;

  const component = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <React.Fragment>
        <dynamicComponent />
      </React.Fragment>
    </Provider>
  );

  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const app = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(component));
```

**Error:**

"*Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.*"

Things I've already had a look at include this answer below, but I'm not sure how to wrap such a function inside (what I presume) the Provider component?

[Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458334/functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-this-may-happen-if-you-return-a-compon?rq=1)

Comment: Try to put a Capital first letter for your component : `const DynamicComponent = componentFunc;` ... <DynamicComponent />

Comment: @Jayffe fair call, but that doesn't work I'm afraid. Same error.

Comment: are you missing render() ?

Comment: @RohanVeer added a bit more code to give you context ;)

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWERING OWN QUESTION:**
Turned out to be a problem with the client's hydrate. This piece of code above was fine all along - :facepalm: