# How do I wrap this child in an Higher Order Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, higher-order-components

```
const LoggedInView = (props) => <Text>You are logged in!</Text>
export default withAuth(LoggedInView)


const withAuth = (component) => <AuthRequired>{ component }</AuthRequired>


const AuthRequired = (props) => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)
    if(!context.auth){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
               <Text>You need to login . Click here</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return props.children 
}
```

My `<AuthRequired>` view works fine, but my `withAuth` does not.

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the order of the component declaration. Ensure that you define withAuth before using it.

By moving the withAuth declaration to the top, it should resolve the issue. Ensure that withAuth is defined before it is used in the export statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HOCs take a component and return another component.  You're taking a component and returning a React node, not a component. [Docs reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

In your case, you should be able to do something like:

```
const withAuth = (Component) => (props) => <AuthRequired><Component ...props /></AuthRequired>
```

It might be easier to understand as:

```
function withAuth(Component) {
    return function WithAuthHOC(props) {
        return (
            <AuthRequired>
                <Component ...props />
            </AuthRequired>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Auxiliary component. It is a higher order component. Auxiliary element is something that does not have semantic purpose but exist for the purpose of grouping elements, styling, etc. Just create a component named `Aux.js` and put this on it:

```
const aux = ( props ) => props.children;

export default aux;
```

Then wrap `withAuth` with Aux.

```
const withAuth = (component) => {
     return ( 
           <Aux> 
               <AuthRequired>{ component }</AuthRequired>
           </Aux> 
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

It looks like there's an issue with the order of the component declaration. Ensure that you define `withAuth` before using it. Here's the corrected order:

```js
const withAuth = (component) => <AuthRequired>{component}</AuthRequired>

const LoggedInView = (props) => <Text>You are logged in!</Text>
export default withAuth(LoggedInView)

const AuthRequired = (props) => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)
    if (!context.auth) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>You need to login. Click here</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return props.children
}
```

By moving the `withAuth` declaration to the top, it should resolve the issue. Ensure that `withAuth` is defined before it is used in the export statement.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you cannot return a function as children in React. How about you trying this?

```
const LoggedInView = <div>You are logged in!</div>;
```

This code works when I tried on my laptop.

Please, take a look at this link: [Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458334/functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-this-may-happen-if-you-return-a-compon)

Comment: It seems there might be a bit of confusion in your suggestion. The issue in the original question is not related to returning a function as children in React. The problem lies in the `withAuth` HOC (Higher Order Component) and its usage.
---
Your proposed solution of changing `LoggedInView` to a constant JSX element might not address the core problem. The issue appears to be with the `withAuth` HOC, which wraps the `LoggedInView` component with the `AuthRequired` component.
---
I would recommend focusing on the `withAuth` function and ensuring it correctly wraps the passed component