# React-Redux Class Component mapStateToProps error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Not able to access the redux store current state in a Class component.

It shows up console error

*Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.*

When I tried to implement the same using a function component with useSelector and useDispatch, everything works as expected. What has gone wrong over here?

**reducer.js**

```
let initialState={
    count:0
}

const reducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_INCREMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                count:state.count+1
            };
        default: return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

**action.js**

```
const Increment=()=>{
    return {
        type:ADD_INCREMENT
    }
}
```

**store.js**

```
import reducer from './reducer';

const store=createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

**Class Component**

```
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    
    const mapStateToProps=state=>{
        return {
            count:state.count
        }
    }

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return {
        count:()=>dispatch(action.Increment())
    }
}
    
    class Orders extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Count: {this.props.count} </h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Orders);
```

In App.js the entire container is wrapped with Provider and store is passed as props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458334/functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-this-may-happen-if-you-return-a-compon) read more about react basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You've named your state and your action both `count`, the latter is the one injected as a prop.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        count: state.count  // <-- name conflict
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        count: () => dispatch(action.Increment()) // <-- name conflict
    }
}
```

## Solution

Provide different names, `count` for the state, maybe `increment` for the action.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  count: state.count,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  increment: () => dispatch(action.Increment())
})
```