# Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working with react-redux, and I use stateless components

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGZQR.png)

[This is my index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXp6z.png)

[My app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJGAP.png)

[the store is in another index.js file, inside a folder called redux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJdBY.png)

I have tried NewHOC, but I can't get rid of the error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What's `RouterDirectory` component looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458334/functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-this-may-happen-if-you-return-a-compon) since you mentioned "NewHOC".

With that in mind, ensure that in all your components you make use of a `return` statement if they are [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) or have a render method if they are class based components.

Based on your screenshots, it seems `RouterDirectory` is the likely culprit as the screenshots you did upload look fine but we can't see RouterDirectory.

If you can provide the code for `RouterDirectory` we can help you further.